# Want to learn SOA in Macbook, Need to install JAR file

Tags: java, jar, virtual-machine, fatal-error

Unrecognized option: -jar/Users/jagadeesh/Downloads/V983385-01_1of2/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Is it possible for you to describe some more details how and what you have done and how did you configure your system before starting? There is only little information and we cannot go further before you would write.

Comment: There needs to be a space between `-jar` and the filename. If that isn’t the problem, please edit the question to show exactly what command was run as well as the output, and use the code formatting button in the question editor to ensure it displays properly when rendered.

Comment: Jagadeeshs-MacBook-Air:~ jagadeesh$ java -jar/Users/jagadeesh/Downloads/V983385-01_1of2/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar
Unrecognized option: -jar/Users/jagadeesh/Downloads/V983385-01_1of2/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: @MNEMO added in comments

Comment: Don't clarify in comments, please edit your question.

Comment: if you typed that command by yourself, Tim would be right and you need one more space between -jar and /. If your command is auto generated by some other programs, you'd better write down that situation. You are allowed to edit your question directly instead of adding explanations in comments.